# Jmeter delay between threads

Tags: for-loop, groovy, jmeter

I am using JMeter for performance testing. I am using csv file and there are 8 lines of data. I want to execute 3 threads in parallel at a time.
1,2,3 - execute in parallel
1 minute time delay
then 4,5,6 - parallel
1 minute time delay
then 
7,8 - parallel execution

I am using JSR223 timer. I used the below code:

```
if(ctx.getThreadNum()%3==0) {
   sleep(60000);
```

}

Here its sleeping at thread 3 and 6 but not as I mentioned above. Could someone please provide a idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be easier to switch to [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter/) like:

- Parallel Controller

  - 1
  - 2
  - 3
- [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) for delay
- Parallel Controller

  - 4
  - 5
  - 6
- Flow Control Action for delay
- Parallel Controller

  - 7
  - 8

The similar behaviour can be achieved using [Synchronizing Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) if you cannot or unwilling to use the Parallel Controller